# Beacon not catch more the 10 meter distance in android

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, distance, beacon

I have used `@hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager` npm

I want to scan Beacon which has a long distance, this is working for IOS device but not in android

Please check my code,

```
  `const region = {
      identifier: "bookify",
      uuid: uuid,
    };
    // Tells the library to detect iBeacons
    Beacons.init();
    Beacons.detectIBeacons();
    // Start detecting all iBeacons in the nearby
    const scanBeaconAndroid = async () => {
      try {
         Beacons.setForegroundScanPeriod(1000);
         await Beacons.startMonitoringForRegion(region);
         await Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
         console.log(`Beacons ranging started succesfully!`);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Beacons ranging not started, error: ${err}`);
      }
    };
    scanBeaconAndroid();
    // Print a log of the detected iBeacons (1 per second)
    Beacons.BeaconsEventEmitter.addListener("beaconsDidRange", (data) => {
      eventCount1++;
      if (eventCount1 == 30) {
        eventCount1 = 0;
        beaconAction()
      }
     
    });
  }`
```

Comment: Solved: I got solutions. Multiple time register events cause this problem. I have put "beaconsDidRange" even code in useEffect, now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that your code is causing the difference in detection distance.  The more likely cause is hardware Bluetooth antenna variations on your Android device.  **Different phone models sometimes have significant variations in the distance they can transmit and receive.**

To check this, install an off the shelf Beacon scanner/transmitter app like by [BeaconScope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US&gl=US) and see if you get similar results.  In this app, I have taken care to make sure the scanning and transmitting are using the highest range allowed by the Android hardware.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung, I got solutions. Multiple time register events cause this problem. I have put "beaconsDidRange" even code in useEffect, now working fine